# Error converting data type nvarchar to float in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

```
select sum(cast(mmax as float) 
from table
```

`mmax` is of datatype `nvarchar` and the value is 
string,int,decimal, value

I trying to sum of like value 17.50,35.00.

I am avoiding string value in where clause

But not solved this problem

Error is thrown

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try to identify which values can't be converted to float first, so you can exclude them from the SELECT. `SELECT mmax FROM table WHERE ISNUMERIC(mmax) = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String/Varchar values with commas such as "10,000" pass the IsNumeric() test but do not cast/convert into numeric types without raising an error.

You can replace the commas and perform the cast and sum operation:

```
select sum(cast(replace(mmax,',','') as float))
from tbl
where isnumeric(maxx)>0
```

Comment: actually query run on sql 2005 but fail on sql 2008 but resolved my issue    in given solution Thnks

Answer (score 0):

One of the values cannot be converted to a float. You may have a million values that can convert if one (has a letter O instead of a 0 for example) you will get that message.